# TlbImp.exe in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, interop

I was looking to use TlbImp.exe to create some dlls for a Excel Library 11.0. Looking at the docs I should expect to find it in the SDK bin, something like:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin

But when I go there it is empty. If i do a search in Windows Explorer i get the following:

[image]

So my question is whether or not, TlbImp.exe is still the way to go or has it been further integrated into Visual 2012?

If it is still the way to go, which version of tool should I be using? Does it matter with regard to which framework the resulting .dll will be expected to run on?

Answer (score 3):

> Looking at the docs I should expect to find it in the SDK bin,
>   something like:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin

That's why I tried to look on it in every foder, guess what? **I've found it!**

It is here!

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

The real problem is that, I need to install .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0 in order to `use` and `search` it.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why this is down voted. Please provide explanation if doing so

Comment: Strangely TlbImp.exe was not there for me (in windows 7), I even tried installing "windows 7 and .NET framework 3.5 SP1" https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3138 - still no luck :/